# Relation between basis of a vector space and those of kernel, image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. If we have a basis of V such that a part of basis mapped under T gives a basis of the image of T, is it true that the rest of the vectors in the basis of V indeed form a basis of the kernel of T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no reason that the remaining basis vectors should be in the kernel at all. All you can say is that the kernel is a complementary subspace to the one spanned by the first set of basis vectors (those whose images under$~T$ span the image space), so one could keep the first set of basis vectors and replace the second set by a *different* set (still making the whole a basis) such that the second set becomes a basis of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a specific counter-example. Let $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ be $T(x,y,z)=x+y$. Then $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ such that $\{T(e_1)\}$ is a basis for $\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}\im T=\Bbb R$ but $\{e_2,e_3\}$ is not a basis for $\ker T$.